# Why does my script not print entire contents of json file to csv

Tags: python-3.x

I have some json files that I need to convert to csv.

I have written a very simple script, but the results are unexpected.  Instead of having all contents of the json file written to the csv file, I only get the top level name with each letter separated by a comma.  Here's the json file contents:

```
{"drivers": [{"id": 91907, "groupId": 9039, "vehicleId": 212014918234488, "username": "abrauer"},
 {"id": 134763, "groupId": 9039, "vehicleId": 212014918234742, "username": "abarbosa"},
 {"id": 134764, "groupId": 9039, "vehicleId": 212014918234709, "username": "btoole"},
 {"id": 134766, "groupId": 9039, "vehicleId": 212014918234773, "username": "bheinsohn"}]}
```

and the code:

```
import csv
import json

infile = open("driver.json","r")
outfile = open("driver.csv","w")

writer = csv.writer(outfile)
for row in json.loads(infile.read()):

    writer.writerow(row)
```

The results are as follows:

d,r,i,v,e,r,s.  Should I expect to remove {"drivers": from the file before trying to convert?

Update...
I tried removing {"drivers": from the file, as well as the trailing '}', and the results is just as strange.  Now, all i get are the attributes without the values.

```
id,groupId,vehicleId,username
id,groupId,vehicleId,username
id,groupId,vehicleId,username
id,groupId,vehicleId,username
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats going on is that your for loop is iterating over the keys of the json dictionary so you're calling `writer.writerow('drivers')`. Since strings are iterable in python, `writer.writerow` is interpreting each character in drivers a column in the row.

The best way to handle this is instead of using a `csv.writer` object, use a `csv.DictWriter` object ([Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)). Your code would then look something like:

```
with open('driver.csv','w') as csv_f:
     drivers = json.loads(infile.read())['drivers']
     fields = list(drivers[0].keys())

     dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_f, fieldnames=fields)

     dict_writer.writeheader()
     for driver in drivers:
          dict_writer.writerow(driver)
```